# Where do you go when a Portal closes from the other side?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, planes, portals, princes-of-the-apocalypse

What would happen to the PCs who

> enter one of the elemental portals, with one of them wielding the elemental weapon, causing it to close when it touches?  Are the characters trapped on the elemental plane, where they must try to find another portal to escape, or are they forced back to the material plane, such as opposite what happens to the elemental princes when their portal closes.

Which plane do they end up on?

Comment: Typing `>!` at the start of a line will allow you to make a spoiler tag.  I have added them for you here, but if you would like to re-word the question to allow it to have part in spoilers, and part not, you are more than welcome to.

Comment: So, the PC is wielding the elemental weapon, but walking backwards through the portal so that the weapon touches it once they're already mostly through? Or holding it behind their back as they cross the threshhold?

Comment: Or the PC is following other PCs in and being third in line, pop, two people are now on the other side

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> They would be stuck in the elemental plane till they could find another way out.

Ask yourself, "If you walk through a door then some one closes it behind you, which side of the door are you on?"

> A portal is the same concept except instead of being a door between 2 rooms, its a door between 2 planes.  It would be different if it was a spell that projected you to the elemental planes.  In that case your self isn't actually in the elemental plane, and if the spell got cut off the projection would disappear and you would wake up at your original location. This would be similar to what happens when the connection gets lost on a video call.

Comment: But making the entire answer a single spoiler block is too boring. I'm going to leave some non-key portions out, or what was already spoiled by, like, the q title. @KorvinStarmast

Comment: I'm going to support this answer for one very good reason- it is _exactly_ how I ruled it when I finished DMing this campaign last month.

Comment: @Mindwin good call